# upper bound for the integral of a root

Tags: integration, inequality

I have two orthonormal Polynomials $f,g:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)\rho(x)dx=\begin{cases}1 \text{ if }f=g,\\ 0 \text{ if } f\neq g\end{cases}$.
$\rho:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a (weight) function.
Now I want to find out, whether it holds:
$\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}\rho(x)dx\leq \begin{cases}1 \text{ if }f=g,\\ 0 \text{ if } f\neq g\end{cases}$.

I don't think it changes anything, but actually $x=X$ is a random variable (beta-distribution) and $\rho$ its density function so we could change my question into whether $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{f(X)g(X)})\leq \mathbb{E}(f(X)g(X))$ where $f$ and $g$ are Jakobi-Polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Weighted Jensen inequality and concavity of $\sqrt{t}$ should suffice.